# How to call an API.ai agent from within a POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, api-design, dialogflow-es

I know this is likely a javascript / node.js noob question, so I apologize in advance. In my defense, I am fluent in R... but am just trying to figure out node.js so I can hit my databases with APIs and do automated R calls.

Using the API.ai node.js [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apiai), I am able to run the following code:

```js
var apiai = require('apiai');
var app = apiai('f20a022f27dd463fa28f8b24a67ad5e7');

var request = app.textRequest('Hello!', {
  'sessionId': 123456
});

request.on('response', function(response) {
  console.log(response);
  console.log(response.result.fulfillment.speech);
  console.log(response.result.metadata.intentName);
});

request.on('error', function(error) {
  console.log(error);
});

request.end();
```

And get the following console results:

```js
{ id: '784f3622-7448-435c-a4f0-20a782ae29c5',
  timestamp: '2016-11-07T20:59:10.3Z',
  result:
   { source: 'agent',
     resolvedQuery: 'Hello!',
     action: '',
     actionIncomplete: false,
     parameters: {},
     contexts: [ [Object] ],
     metadata:
      { intentId: '87ac68b3-462d-479a-8dbb-c05d816db3b4',
        webhookUsed: 'false',
        intentName: 'welcome' },
     fulfillment: { speech: 'Welcome to the jungle!', messages: [Object] },
     score: 1 },
  status: { code: 200, errorType: 'success' },
  sessionId: '123456' }
Welcome to the jungle!
welcome
```

All well and good.

But I don't just want to get console results. I want to pass the values in response.result.fulfillment.speech and response.result.metadata.intentName on as the output of an API POST call. (Actually I'll eventually be writing them to a database, but since I can't even get them to send back as the output of an API POST call, that is not feasible yet.)

So. I tried this approach:

```js
var express    = require("express");
var app = express();
var apiai = require('apiai');
var app2 = apiai('f20a022f27dd463fa28f8b24a67ad5e7');

app.post("/",function(req,res){
  var keyword = req.query.keyword;
  console.log(keyword);

var request = app2.textRequest('Hello.', {'sessionId': 123456});

  request.on('response', function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    res.json(response);
  });

  request.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log(error);

  });
});
app.listen(3000);
```

And all I got was a console line that said **"Hello."**, by which it appears that the code didn't get any farther than console.log(keyword).

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working? Even if it is totally simple.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Rucker. You have to add `request.end();` call after `request.on('error'...` as in your first code sample.

Comment: @xVir: And that worked great! Simple indeed. Thank you very, very much... I had been hitting my head against that for a day now.

Comment: I'm glad it helped :) This call is need to start request process.